# Android: Custom AlertDialog has different text color

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dialog

I created a custom layout for an AlertDialog, and it works fine, 
But i have a problem with the text style of my layout.

This is the layout for my alertDialog:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"      
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/namedialoglable"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/profilename" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/namedialoginput"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/namedialoglable"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:text="@string/defaultname" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is that the text into the default AlertDialog is white, and in my custom dialog is black. I just want to use the same color used into other AlertDialog.

How to do that?

**EDIT**
To be more clear: 
I want to keep the father text color, not force my custom dialog color to be white. I think that AlertDialog use system color, so my alert need to keep the same color

Answer (score 0):

Why wont you just apply:

```
android:textColor="@android:color/white"
```

to the `Views` you want with while text color.

Also look into styles and themes to achieve what you wnat:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#PlatformStyles

Comment: but i don't want it to be white, to be more clear, i want the same color of the other dialogs. For example in android 4 the dialog is white with black text, i want to keep the color from the father class!

Comment: then you might want to look into styles and themes: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#PlatformStyles

Answer (score 0):

Ok in my case, i found another solution. 
Since my need is to have only a message and an input text into the dialog box, the best solution is to create a layout with only an EditText, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"      
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/namedialoginput"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"        
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:text="@string/defaultname" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And for the message text, using the builder method: setMessage:

```
    builder.setView(content)
        .setTitle("Profile Name")
        .setMessage(R.string.profilename);
```

In that way, i am sure that i keep the other dialog boxes format.